# Star point selection in Altium Designer

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, grounding

I want to have a star topology for my circuit's ground in *Altium Designer*, So I defined this rule from **Design** -> **Rules**:

[image: PCB rules in Altium Designer]

It's all fine until this step, But I **can't** select where to be the **source** of this star topology; It selects one of my component's GND pad arbitrarily. How can I do that? (I prefer to use regulator GND pad as the star source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type to 'source' in the pad dialog:

[image]